# How to change project owner in Google BigQuery after accidentally assigning service account ownership?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-console

Accidentally made service account owner of a Google BigQuery project

I created Google BigQuery project in my Google Cloud Console to pull in raw data from a Google Analytics 4 property. I'm fairly new to GCS and BigQuery so I accidentally made my user account an Editor and a service account the Owner of the project. Because of that, I can no longer make other IAM permission changes, including granting access to other users.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkwPH.png)

I tried to look through the resources from Google but it's too convoluted. Is there a way for me to change myself back to being the owner of the project? Thank you very much for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete), an approach that maybe works is try to execute an IAM update authenticated as the service account:

1. Download and install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
2. Execute the commands:

```bash
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>
```

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> \
    --member=user:<YOUR_EMAIL> --role='roles/owner' \
```

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding

Comment: Thank you Damiao for the suggestion! I'm getting an Error that says: ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User [firebase-measurement-system-gs@festival-XXXXXX-org-ga4.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [festival-XXXXXX-org-ga4:setIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): Policy update access denied.

Comment: In your print, the account with Owner role is the `firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com`, so you need to use it credentials. You can try the [`--impersonate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--impersonate-service-account) command flag

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Here's what i wrote `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding festival-sundance-org-ga4 --member=user:laXXXX.com --role=roles/owner` but that produced `ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User [firebase-measurement-system-gs@festival-XXXXXX-org-ga4.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [festival-XXXXXX-org-ga4:setIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): Policy update access denied.`